# How to change log in screen resolution to 1024*768 in Lubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, resolution, lubuntu, login-screen

I am new to Lubuntu or any ubuntu OS. Please in detail answer will be appreciated.

Comment: are you talking about the login screen itself - or the desktop screen resolution? If the latter, have you looked at preferences - monitor settings?  What is your graphics card and have you installed any graphics drivers?

Comment: I actually do not have lxde here but anybody that can create an answer that involves changing the resolution in lubuntu would be great since that would change the login as well.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!